# Why say "мне не место", not "мне нет места"?

Tags: грамматика

> Таким людям, как я, **не место** в этом мире.

I wonder why "не" instead of "нет" precedes the noun "место" in this expression -- not to mention the lack of the genitive "места". Compared to:

> Таким людям, как я, **нет места** в этом мире.

Comment: *не место* means *don't belong in* and usually have disapproving connotation, i.e. a person is so bad that they don't deserve being here, *нет места* - *can't find a place* having a melancholic connotation, that of disillusionment and despair, there's no Genitive in the first phrase since *не* functions differently than *нет*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These sentences have different meanings:

> Таким людям, как я, нет места в этом мире.
>   People like me have no place in this world.

While:

> Таким людям, как я, не место в этом мире.
>   People like me are not suitable for this world.

**"мне здесь не место"** means **"I shouldn't be here (and maybe better should be elsewhere)"**

Answer (score 2):

You can say both way. While **нет места** can be said also as literally meaning "there is no space", **не место** always means *nobody happy to see you* or *you should not be here* not because of lack of space.

Answer (score 2):

Both expressions are valid, with different meaning:

- Мне здесь нет места. - There is no place/room for me here.
- Мне здесь не место. - I shouldn't be here. / This place is not for me.

As to the grammar, here is my unvalidated theory: место is used as a predicative (предикатив). As predicatives are not inflected, место has also lost its inflection in this role:

- Мне здесь не хорошо.
- Мне здесь не спится.
- Мне здесь не место.

Comment: also e.g. *вам здесь не дом отдыха*

Comment: *Мне здесь не спится* is probably unrelated because it's just an impersonal sentence with a conventional predicate

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with the theory of this phenomenon, but here's an intuitive answer.

First, why `не` instead of `нет`. In English one can say both `there is not a place` where `not` negates `is`, and `there is no place` where `no` -- at least, in my understanding -- negates `place`.  Similarly, `нет` in `нет места` sorta means `не есть` (where `есть` is a form of `быть` -- see [here](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB_II))) or `не существует`. In other words, `нет` is not a negation of `места`, but a negation of a verb `существует` that is hidden in this `нет`, so what you are really saying is `не существует места`. On the other hand, `не` in `не место` negates `место` itself.

Second, why `место` instead of `места`. Now that `не` negates `место` is established, there's no reason for `место` to change cases. Drop `не` and you'll see it:

> Таким людям, как я, место в этом мире.

Adding `не` shouldn't change anything as far as cases go -- when you add `не` into `Курица - птица` to say `Курица не птица` you don't switch cases too.